# Is it possible to find sigma levels using a z table?

Tags: objective-c, function, reference

Working on calculating sigma level for an application.  The only way to do that is by finding the z score on the z table.  Is there a reference for that built into xcode?  Is there a function you can use to find z score?  Or can you not do it at all?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE and has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @rmaddy ok let me rephrase that, is it possible to find sigma level using objective c